# Error updating linux - "Could not resolve kali.download"

Tags: linux, updates, kali-linux

I'm not able to run sudo apt-get update, keep getting the following error:

```
#apt-get update
Ign:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Err:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Could not resolve 'kali.download'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not resolve 'kali.download'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've seen in other posts that it could be solved for them by modifying the `etc/apt/sources.list` adding "`deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main contrib non-free`" or "`deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`".

I've tried this solution, but it did not solve my issue.

Also I've notices usually this error in other users can't fetch kali.org, but in my case it is kali.download.

I'm able to see in the browser the index of http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling properly, but can't download InRelease.

Any hints on this?

Comment: Try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429729/apt-get-update-error-in-kali-linux-after-dist-upgrade) solution

Comment: Hi Ramhound, indeed I had tried that one before opening the question. I tried all 3 solutions but still getting the same error as the one included in the original post :(

Comment: Can you ping kali.download? You absolutely should be able to if you can’t then you have a DNS problem

Comment: It's true I can't ping kali.download even tho I can ping kali.org, but I have changed the DNS to googles (8.8.8.8) and still getting the same. Any tip?

Comment: Disable the firewall ?

Comment: FW is already disabled. Doing a nslookup to kali.dowload through google's DNS I get "canonical name = security.mac.vodafone.es." so I believe it is due to the "Secure DNS" option on Vodafone. Checking it.

Comment: Two things:   (a) does another computer on the same network have Internet and work?  (2) are you updating an old version of Kali?

Comment: @Ody - If you have secure DNS enabled and you configured to use a non-secure DNS provider that would be the reason its not working

Comment: SOLVED - In case someone else bumps into this error, it was due to "SecureNet" from Vodafone ISP in Spain. After disabling it, it finally is able to resolve kali.download domain and update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error**: While trying to run `apt update`, if fails and gives the error:

```
Ign:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Err:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Could not resolve 'kali.download'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Could not resolve 'kali.download'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

To review if it is the same cause, run the following command:

```
nslookup kali.download 8.8.8.8
```

And it should give an output like the following:

```
Server:         212.166.132.192
Address:        212.166.132.192#53

Non-authoritative answer:
kali.download   canonical name = security.mac.vodafone.es.
```

To solve it you should deactivate the 'SecureNet' feature from your ISP client platform.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were like me, having the `/etc/apt/source.list` with `https` instead of plain `http` was the issue.

Removing the `s` did the job for me.

Comment: There should be no need to use http instead of https these days

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve this my replacing https inplace of http in the `/etc/apt/source.list`

This is my source.list

```
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

I'm also using WSL2.